# jquery DataTable push td in array

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have datatable,
i want every time you click on a tr:
push all td in tr to javascript array.

It must be using the function:
delegate("tr", "click", function()
    enter code here

```
\$("#example tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
     tablerow = ( \$( this ).text() );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var myArray=[];

("#example tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function() {

  //myArray.push($(this).text());//push all td text
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
     myArray.push($(this).text()); // push each td text to array
  });
```

Comment: Better, so that the values ​​will vary:

\$("#example tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
 var myArray=[];
  //myArray.push(\$(this).text());//push all td text
  \$(this).find('td').each(function(){
     myArray.push(\$(this).text()); // push each td text to array
  
  });
  tablerow = myArray[0];
  //alert(tablerow);

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `delegate()` was superceded by `on()` in version 1.7. If you're not using at least v1.10 you should upgrade it.

Secondly, you can use a `map()` to get all the text from the `td` elements in the row. Try this:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var tdTextArray = $('td', this).map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var tablerow =[];
$("#example tbody").on("click", "tr", function() { // use on instead of delegate
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){ // grep all td
        tablerow.push($( this ).text()); // push td text to array
    });
});
```

Read **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

You can use `insert` for uniquness of `trs` like,

```
var tablerow =[];
$("#example tbody").on("click", "tr", function(ind) { // use on instead of delegate
    var td=$(this).find('td').map(function(){ // grep all td
        return $( this ).text();
    }).get();
    tablerow.splice(ind, 0, td); // unique array for tr index
});
```